# Excluding rows in python using multiple conditions on the same column

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to exclude rows by specifying multiple values for the same column. I have the following dataframe:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 1 |

want to exclude the rows taking values A & B.

Tried the following code:

`new_df = df[~(df['X'] == 'A') & ~(df['X'] == 'B')]`

its not working, the new dataframe has 0 rows

Comment: It looks OK. not sure why it wouldn't work. You could also do `df[~df['X'].isin(['A', 'B'])]`

Comment: Code seems to be okay. You could either try the approach of @SomeDude or this line `df[~((df["X"] == "A") | (df["X"] == "B"))]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use ~

```
df[(~df.X.isin(['A','B']))]
Out[183]: 
   X  Y
2  C  1
3  D  1
```

and also to exclude where X = 'A' and Y = 1

```
df[(~df.X.isin(['A','B']) & (~(df.X=='A') & (df.Y==1)))]
```

Comment: This worked!! Also, what to do to exclude rows that contain A & 1 at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `pd.DataFrame.query`, coming from the SQL world this make make a little more sense and easier to read.

```
df.query("X not in ['A','B']")
```

Output:

```
   X  Y
2  C  1
3  D  1
```